# Append a character at each end of line in a file using Java

Tags: java

I want to put some characters/text at every end of each line in my text file.

test.txt

a

b

c

after appending some characters to each line:

test.txt

a A

b B

c C

This process might happen over one million times.

a A AA AAA...

b B BB BBB...

c C CC CCC...

Is there anyways that I could finish this process by iterating each line and appending string at the end? (I know there is a way to read each line and add a string to the end and write to the new output file. But what I need is just manipulating the same file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert into a file you must rewrite the file (or at least rewrite the file from where you are inserting)

Comment: This is because files are essentially an array of bytes- you can't put something into the middle of the array without somehow "moving" everything that comes after it. It would be like trying to add a new line in the middle of an essay written on lined paper.